# Refreshments to follow

Tags: grammar, phrase-meaning

I got an invitation for my kid's show and at the end of it said:
Refreshments to follow

I believe it is a shortened sentence. What is the original one? What does it mean?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

On invitations, it's common! Refreshments simply means that the program will be followed by snacks and some drinks (soft/cold...anything). [Check the meaning here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/refreshment).

[image: invitation card sample]

Comment: Thank you. So the whole sentence should be like "This show is followed by refreshments"? Why does it become "Refreshments to follow" instead of "Refreshments to be followed", a passive voice? Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes. Also, the limited space. Both ways, it's okay.

Comment: Maulik: Both ways are *not* OK.  "Refreshments to be followed" doesn't make sense, because it means that the refreshments will be followed by something else.  "Refreshments to follow" is just a shortened version of "Refreshments *are* to follow".

Comment: Thank you stangdon! I think it's the word "follow" that confuses me. Can we just say "Refreshments follow"? What is the difference between "Refreshments are to follow" and "Refreshment follow". Thank you again!

Comment: @quietrack1 - The simple present, "Refreshments follow" just states a general truth or something that always happens, like "Birds lay eggs" or "Summer follows spring."  **Are to** is a form of *to be to*, which is used when describing plans or orders: https://blog.abaenglish.com/advanced-grammar-to-be-to/